# How to test TCP socket behavior of the Intenet connection breaking on a Windows build-server?

Tags: c++, windows, visual-studio, azure-devops, tcp

I am building a test in Visual Studio to test reconnect-logic when a connection gets broken.  It is easy to do this on a local computer, in that I just disconnect the internet connection.  But, how do I do that on a Build-Server (specifically, Azure)?